# HTML "download" attribute not working inside a section

Tags: html, css

I've created a download button, but clicking it doesn't start the download and the cursor is not changing to pointer. The download button is inside a div which is inside a section.

When I put the button outside the section, it works. But I have to put it inside the section. Where did I gone wrong?

```css
.dwnld_bt {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  padding: 1% 10% 4% 10%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.profiles {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  column-gap: 5%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.dwnd-button1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 12%;
  left: -50%;
}
```

```html
<section id="downloads" class="dwnld_bt">
  <div class="profiles">
    <div class="profile1">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" class="prof1" alt="Profile"/>
      <a class="dwnd-button1" download="download/Company-Profile" href="download/Company-Profile.pdf">
        <img class="dwnd-img1"
          src="https://via.placeholder.com/50/555" alt="Download Icon">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] so you know how to use this site. "Thanks" comments are discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the `z-index` property set to `-1` on the `.dwnld_bt` class. Any element with a negative z-index, it is positioned behind its parent container and other elements, which can cause the click event to not trigger on the download button. Check the working snippet below.

```css
.dwnld_bt {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  padding: 1% 10% 4% 10%;
}
```

```html
<section id="downloads" class="dwnld_bt">
  <div class="profiles">
    <div class="profile1">
      <img src="IMAGES/profile1.png" class="prof1" alt="Profile" />
      <a class="dwnd-button1" download="download/Company-Profile" href="download/Company-Profile.pdf"><img class="dwnd-img1" src="IMAGES/Download.webp" alt="Download Icon"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```